# How to Disable all Kernel process schedulers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduled-tasks

How can I **disable** all the kernel process scheduling. Is there a configuration of something that I can use to do this.

Comment: Complete disabling scheduling would make your system **unusable**, so it is hardly there is such option. What do you want to achive?

Comment: You can compile the kernel from source and disabling all the configuration related to the scheduler. But doing so your kernel will only run ... the kernel, which is a bit ... selfish.

If you are not experienced with it you could look at the gentoo manual or more specifically the linux from scrach guide which are really well made and can provide you with information about how to compile your kernel.

Comment: I am basically pinning the process to a particular CPU. I don't want kernel to reschedule that process in some other CPU. No load balancing should happening between the CPU's

Comment: look up cpu_set() ..